# Remove unused Bookmarks

Tags: c#, migradoc

I am working with c#, I am making a PDF out of my data. I do this with MigraDoc and PDFsharp.

I have some dynamic info that is bookmarked. The issue is that when there is no data to add I don’t add that certain section, the TOC entry says : "Bookmark 'bookmarkName' is not defined within the document"

The table of contents is created before the rest of the PDF so trying to do an `if` statement does not work. I want to remove all unused/empty bookmarks.

Comment: Sounds like a good issue to help you with - but can you provide more detail?  A [mcve], or something to validate where we can insert a check against empty bookmarks?

Comment: You do not have to create the TOC first, you can add items to the TOC section when you add the corresponding data section - that is the clean way. You can also remove items from the TOC section when you later find you do not need them - this requires more code, is not quite that clean, but is still relatively simple.

Answer (score 0):

Nomenclature: you add bookmarks in the data section, you add links to the bookmarks in the table of contents (TOC). You want to remove broken links (unused bookmarks are invisible and there is no need to remove them).

MigraDoc is highly dynamic. Before starting the rendering process you can modify anything.

The `Section` has an `Elements` member that gives you access to the `Paragraph` objects and others in the section. Each `Paragraph` has an `Elements` object that gives you access to the `Text` objects etc. that make up the `Paragraph`.

Thus it is possible to enumerate through the document, building lists of hyperlinks and bookmarks in the first run and removing hyperlinks to non-existing bookmarks in the second run. Can be done, but the code will be complicated.

As noted, MigraDoc is highly dynamic. You can add a TOC section and leave it empty.

Approach one: when adding the data, pass the TOC section to the code that adds the data and let that code update the TOC section. Easy to add the famous `if` statement here so you only have a hyperlink in the TOC section when you also have the bookmark in the contents section.

Approach two: when adding the data, register all created bookmarks in a list. Create the TOC in the last step, only adding hyperlinks to existing bookmarks.

Approach three (deprecated): when adding a link to the TOC table, keep a reference to each paragraph. Also build a list of bookmarks added by the data code. This way you have a list of paragraphs that require modification, you can easily remove all their elements and add new content without a hyperlink. I wouldn't do it this way, but it can be done.